How can I utilize my VSCode extension to override the default code folding strategy employed by VSCode?
I have developed a code-folding plugin for a specific framework based on Python, primarily focusing on folding branch logic code. The framework functions correctly across most scenarios, but there is one case where it gets overridden by the default folding strategy.
The specific framework code is like:
self.func1() \
    .if_(condition1)
      .func2() \
      .func3() \
    .end_()

And my code-folding extension is defined as:
class MyFoldingRangeProvider implements vscode.FoldingRangeProvider {
  public provideFoldingRanges(document: vscode.TextDocument, context: vscode.FoldingContext, token: vscode.CancellationToken): 
    vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.FoldingRange[]> {
      const ranges: vscode.FoldingRange[] = [];
      let stack: number[] = [];
      const if_pattern = /(.*?)\.if_\((.*?)\)/;
      const end_pattern = /(.*?)\.end_(.*?)/;
      for (let i = 0; i < document.lineCount; i++) {
         const lineText = document.lineAt(i).text.trim();
         if (lineText.match(if_pattern)) {
           stack.push(i);
         } else if (lineText.match(end_pattern)) {
           if (stack.length > 0) {
             const startLine = stack.pop();
             if (startLine !== undefined) {
               ranges.push(new vscode.FoldingRange(startLine, i));
             }
           }
         }
       }
       return ranges;
    }
}

This extension is capable of achieving the folding demonstrated in the aforementioned example. However, when confronted with a scenario such as the following, the entire code segment is subjected to a default fold due to being interpreted as a single line of code. This default strategy supersedes the approach delineated by my extension. Consequently, even func3 becomes subject to the folding action, encapsulated within the collapsed section of code due to the IDE's default behavior overriding the extension's intended functionality.
self.if_(condition1) \
      .func1() \
      .func2() \
    .end_() \
    .func3()

How can I utilize my VSCode extension to override the default code folding strategy employed by VSCode?
I hope to be able to override the default strategy of VSCode with my custom extension.
